# How to prevent WWW-Authenticate header in response with authenticateBasicAsync directive?

Tags: akka, spray, akka-http

When using the authenticateBasicAsync, how can the WWW-Authenticate response header be omitted?

The problem is that a Javascript api (ajax) is calling the akka-http service and the browser is displaying login window when auth fails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Create a custom rejection handler to get lower level control over the response:

```
def customRejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
.handle { 
    case AuthenticationFailedRejection(cause, challenge) => 
    complete(HttpResponse(StatusCodes.Unauthorized)) 
}
.result()
```

Then pass to a handleRejections directive.